# How to use where inside STUFF sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So i want to display multiple row data into one column, and i found that using stuff on sql server can do it.

but i got stuck on how to use where with parent field inside the stuff query.

i tried using the parent field with the same name but i got an error, and i also tried using aliases on the parent field but same error.

```
SELECT 
id_collector, 
branch 
= STUFF(
    (
    SELECT 
    ', '+ a.group_branch_id
    from AMAS.dbo.tbl_area_collector a
    where id_collector = id_collector
    for XML path('')), 1, 1, ''
      )
from AMAS.dbo.tbl_area_collector GROUP BY id_collector
```

Comment: You are near to your solution. Please use alias everywhere while you select any column from `outer table` (i.e.: AMAS.dbo.tbl_area_collector AS T1)  or `inner table` (i.e.: AMAS.dbo.tbl_area_collector AS T2). Please never assign column value `branch =` while you are able to assign your column name using `AS branch`. I think there is no need of `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: If you target SQL Server 2017 you can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) . This makes it a lot easier to use string aggregation with complex queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify *all* column references in your query!  Then your queries are more likely to work the first time:

```
SELECT tac.id_collector, 
       STUFF( (SELECT ', ' + tac2.group_branch_id
               FROM AMAS.dbo.tbl_area_collector tac2
               WHERE tac2.id_collector = tac.id_collector
               FROM XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as branches
FROM AMAS.dbo.tbl_area_collector tac
GROUP BY tac.id_collector;
```